# Fill diagonal elements of array with Numbers

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I.ve got `2D array` amount of raws and columns are the same.

I need to fill diagonal elements like this:

```
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
```

Here is my code:

```
   private static void fillDiagonal() {
        int[][] arr = new int[3][3];
        //  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                arr[i][i] = 1;
                arr[0][2] = 1;
                arr[2][0] = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
    }
```

It's worked, but I need to change it from Hardcode values.

```
arr[0][2] = 1;
arr[2][0] = 1;
```

To fill it with loop

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for two `for` loops. You can do this in `O(n)`, as for values on the diagonal `y` and `x` will be identical.

To get both diagonals you need to start once on the left using `i` and once on the right using `arr.length - i - 1`. As `i` is increasing you will gradually move from left to right for `i` and at the same time move from right to left for `arr.length - i - 1`.

This will work for any `n x n` matrix.

```java
private static void fillDiagonal() {
    int[][] arr = new int[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i][i] = 1;
        arr[arr.length - i - 1][i] = 1;
    }
    Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It only takes a single loop and you only need to iterate across half the length of a side.

```
int[][] result = fillDiagonal(7);   
for (int[] row : result) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

- takes an `int` value to specify a side of the square matrix
- returns the filled matrix
- given a square matrix of size `n x n`
- the the upper left corner `v[0][0]` and the lower right is `v[n-i-1][n-i-1]`.
- these middle values are filled out similarly effective filling in the diagonals going from the corners inward.

```
public static int[][] fillDiagonal(int n) {
    int[][] v = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        v[i][i] = v[i][n-i -1] = v[n-i-1][i] = v[n-i-1][n-i-1] = 1;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that you set those two entries for every iteration of the loops, which is bad. Second, you have a double-nested loop where you don't even use j, so that's bad. Think about this: You want to set 3 entries on the main diagonal and 3 entries on the reverse diagonal. So that should just require one or two loops that execute 3 times, not a double-nested loop.
Third, you realized that the important indices are [0][0],[1][1], and [2][2], which you can index as [i][i] if you make i go from 0 to 2. Now what are the indices in the reverse diagonal? Write them down, and then create a formula based on i and 3 (or in general n) that will be the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void fillDiagonal() {
        int[][] arr = new int[3][3];
        //  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if(i == j) arr[i][j] = 1;
                if(i+j == arr.length - 1) arr[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
    }
```